# SQL copying data with new foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a very tricky problem here.
I have two tables. One is dependent on another by foreign key.
Table 1

| Table1ID | Instance ID | ModifiedBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yevhen |
| 2 | 1 | yevhen |
| 3 | 1 | yevhen |

Table 2

| ID | Instance ID | Table1ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

These are taken as datasets for something named "Scenario".
When somebody creates new scenario, it triggers two stored procedures - one for Table1 and than one for Table2 which are basically replicating this data in the same table with new Instance ID. And that is where we have a problem. Table1 will autoincrement it`s Keys but Table2 will remain with old foreign keys for new instance like this

Table 1

| Table1ID | Instance ID | ModifiedBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yevhen |
| 2 | 1 | yevhen |
| 3 | 1 | yevhen |
| 4 | 2 | yevhen |
| 5 | 2 | yevhen |
| 6 | 2 | yevhen |

Table 2

| ID | Instance ID | Table1ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

How to make Table1ID setted with new ID`s from Table1?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have two stored procs.  But with simultaneous logic like this you should probably do it in the same stored proc.

In that proc, when inserting into table 1, use `output` to capture those newly inserted records.  Those results will give you the inserted primary keys, which you in turn pump into table 2.

```
create table #newRecords (table1id int, [instance id] int);

insert      table1
output      inserted.Table1ID, inserted.[Instance ID] into #newRecords
select      [instance id], modifiedBy 
from        table1;

insert      table2
select      nr.[instance id], nr.table1id
from        #newRecords nr;
```

Your table 2 results from this would be as follows:

| ID | Instance ID | Table1ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | 6 |

Comment: Well the thing is we have more than 2 tables. Basically there is 5 different tables that depends on that one, and all of them containing their own information. The only similarity between them is they all have InstanceID and Table1ID cols. So making all in one SP is not an option I suppose

Comment: There's nothing that prevents you from merging more than two stored procs.  But there may be a design problem.  You may want to give a little more to your example that demonstrates why you feel you couldn't merge procs.

Comment: No, actually you are right. I can merge it all in one sp. Just need to figure out how to do it properly and sort out your solution in my head :D